# How to add an Int to a list of Int while passing the list as an argument?

Tags: list, haskell, fibonacci

I want to generate a list of the first n fibonacci numbers.
I have 3 functions:

- fib2: generates the n-th number
- fib: calls fib2 to make a list of
  those numbers
- fibonacci: only exists so you don't have to pass that
  empty list every time

My problem is pretty simple, but I just can't figure it out.
The line

```
fib n m = fib (n-1) m : (fib2 n)
```

does not work especially the part "m : (fib2 n)". I want to calculate the n-th fibonacci number (with fib2 n) and add it to my list of fibonacci numbers m. I thought ":" adds a new element to a list, but somehow I am using it wrong.

Below the whole code

```
fib2 :: Int -> Int
fib2 0 = 1
fib2 1 = 1
fib2 n = fib2 (n - 1) + fib2 (n - 2)

fib :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
fib 0 m = m
fib n m = fib (n-1) m : (fib2 n)

fibonacci :: Int -> [Int]
fibonacci n = fib n []
```

Comment: Be aware that your approach is very inefficient. Search for "haskell fibonacci" on the site to see more efficient methods.

Comment: Thank you, I'm aware of that. But as you can possibly tell from my relatively stupid problem I'm just beginning with Haskell. This was not about the best way to do this, just to try some "features" of the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found out I'm an idiot. I have to switch the arguments of the ":" function

```
fib n m = fib (n-1) (fib2 n : m)
```

and everything is fine.